# Pandas sort date index column that has a dot format

Tags: python, pandas, date

my index column is a date in format of `%d.%m.%y`  for instance 10.7.2022, however, my dataframe always seems to stay sorted by the day, when displayed.

[image]

This continues until all years are displayed, then it goes to 1.5, and continues, after all months are finished, and then it moves to 2.4.2010. How do I sort this the correct way? I tried `output.sort_index(inplace=True)`, but this is not working

Comment: the screenshot is what is the index column

Comment: If you write `output.index.dtype`, what do you get?

Comment: it says: object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a pandas dataframe by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258949/how-to-sort-a-pandas-dataframe-by-date)

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the dates to actual date data type, this can be done with `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`

Comment: Adjusted the answer for index

Comment: @vogelstein, when a question is an obvious duplicate, flag it and avoid giving an answer, even if it is simple and correct. Unless, of course, you have something to add that was not in the original question. ["Official" policy here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)